# What is the function of adding request attributes when linking to css files?

Tags: css, html

In the head section of the sample html file from the html5boilerplate project, I notice this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=2">
```

Note the `v=2` request variables. I also notice that this is never done for javascript files.
What is the actual function of doing this ?

Comment: It's done for JS files as well. Just have a look at SO's source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?v=2` might be to prevent reading from cache by the browser. It's used when loading dynamic content from a static file, like so:

```
changingListOfStuff.txt?randomUselessPropertyToTrickBrowser=123456789
```

This forces the browser to use this exact file, not a cached version of `changingListOfStuff.txt` previously downloaded and stored by the browser. Caching speeds up loading time, but might provide an older version of the file if it changes rapidly.

Read more about caching here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache

Answer (score 1):

this is just telling the version of the url. This is done to make a fresh request to the server.In case of css as we know to achieve performance some headers are modified so that next time css is served by the browser history.But every time a css is modifed specifically in case of version releases. Browser should make new requests that would happen only when the url changes. So v=2 probaly means a new version is in and the url should freshly fetch the content from css.

Answer (score 1):

This is called cache busting...you can read it here too

http://manikandanc.blogspot.com/2005/11/cache-busting-with-javascript.html

this will avoid client to get the version from browser. When you change the javascript or css , the end client who already visited your  website may get javascript from his cache.

You can increment the version no whenever you deploy the files to the production , so that it will get the latest file